# Store multiple objects in sysdata.rda: R-package development

Tags: r, devtools

I've just stumbled on the possibility to store internal package data in `/R/sysdata.rda`. However, I don't get how I should store multiple objects?

I can store one single object, but I would like to make many more available through `sysdata.rda`. I know it to be possible by looking at the `Dichromats` package, as shown on Hadley R packages website http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html.

I've tried the code below.

```
> devtools::use_data(data, data, internal = TRUE)
Saving data, data as sysdata.rda to C:\Users\USER\Documents\R\package/R

> devtools::use_data(data2, data2, internal = TRUE)
Error: sysdata.rda already exists in C:/Users/User/Documents/R/package/R. Use overwrite = TRUE to overwrite
In addition: Warning message: Saving duplicates only once: data2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is as simple as seperating the different object by a comma.

For example

```
> devtools::use_data(data.frame1, data.frame2, internal = TRUE)
```

Comment: What if you don't want to add all the files at the same time? Is that possible?

Comment: new_object_to_add <- "xyz"
    sysdata_filenames <- load("R/sysdata.rda")
    save(list = c(sysdata_filenames, "new_object_to_add"), file = "R/sysdata.rda")