# R package: writing internal data, but not all at once

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm working on an R package using `usethis`/`devtools`. The package has a few objects I'd like to keep internal, just to keep down the clutter. The structure I was using was to make objects in different files based on their source, all in my `data-raw` folder. For instance, the file `make_laus_codes.R` preps two data frames of lookup codes from the Bureau of Labor Statistics (one internal, called `laus_codes`), and the file `make_decennial_tables.R` preps lookup codes from the Decennial Census (including an internal, `decennial_nums`).

If I make a call like `usethis::use_data(data_name, internal = TRUE)`, I get an error if the `sysdata.rda` file has already been created and I haven't chosen to overwrite it; if I choose to overwrite, it overwrites the whole thing, rather than what I'd expected, which is appending the second object to `sysdata.rda`.

The accepted answer to [Store multiple objects in sysdata.rda: R-package development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529727/5325862) says to call `usethis::use_data(laus_codes, decennial_nums, internal = TRUE)`, but a comment there poses the question of what if these objects aren't being created at the same time, and that's where I'd like to pick up.

A simplified version of my structure is as follows:

**data-raw/make_laus_codes.R:**

```
laus_codes <- data.frame(
  area = c("Connecticut", "Fairfield County", "Hartford County"),
  code = c("ST0900000000000", "CN0900100000000", "CN0900300000000")
)
```

**data-raw/make_decennial_tables.R:**

```
decennial_nums <- c("H002", "H003", "H004", "H005", "H006")
```

**data-raw/make_internal_data.R:**

```
source("./make_laus_codes.R")
source("./make_decennial_tables.R")

usethis::use_data(laus_codes, decennial_nums, internal = TRUE)
```

This works, but it feels awkward and like I'm missing the intended way to do this. Is there a way to do this that is better, more proper, and/or intended by `usethis`? It feels susceptible to bugs and forgetfulness to be sourcing other files this way.

Comment: I would add the corresponding `usethis::use_data` at the end of each R script.

Comment: @F.Privé the problem with that is that for internal data, it only gets written to `sysdata.rda`, so if I try to call `usethis::use_data(internal = T)` multiple times, it either can't, because that file already exists, or has to overwrite.

Comment: Ah ok. What about an `one-file-to-source-them-all.R`?

Comment: @F.Privé that's basically what I'm doing here. It just doesn't seem as foolproof as it should be, like at some point I'm sure I'll update something in `make_decennial_tables` but forget to then rerun `make_internal_data` to save it to `sysdata.rda`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this solution doesn't use `usethis`, I believe it solves your problem concisely:

```
# Let's say you've saved this sysdata in the past
laus_codes <- data.frame(
    area = c("Connecticut", "Fairfield County", "Hartford County"),
    code = c("ST0900000000000", "CN0900100000000", "CN0900300000000")
)
usethis::use_data(laus_codes, internal = TRUE)

# Updating sysdata with objects you've created just now
decennial_nums <- c("H002", "H003", "H004", "H005", "H006")
sysdata_filenames <- load("R/sysdata.rda")
save(list = c(sysdata_filenames, "decennial_nums"), file = "R/sysdata.rda")
```

Comment: Thank you! This might still require me to check what's already written in `sysdata` before I try to append anything new, but that's probably a better practice than just assuming anyway