# devtools::use_data( , internal =TRUE)

Tags: r, package-development

I want to use an array, say `aaa`, as internal data by `devtools::use_data( aaa,internal =TRUE)`.

But this command make only one file `sysdata.rda`. Why ? Why several internal data files does not be allowed to exist?.

I also cannot understand the difference between  internal =TRUE and FALSE.

My motivation of using `internal =true` is a default value of some variable of my function in my package. I want to use some array as a default values, and this default values is not needed for users of my package, hence I consider the array should be included my package as an `internal =TRUE` . **Is this attitude correct ?**

And the R says that use `usethis::use_data()` instead of `devtools::use_data()`. Why ???

REF:
[R package: writing internal data, but not all at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384397/r-package-writing-internal-data-but-not-all-at-once)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`devtools::use_data` has now been deprecated and transferred to the `usethis` package, hence the message; the functions remains the same.

If you set `internal = TRUE` the data will only be accessible by functions of the package internally while if `FALSE` the data will be exported, users will be able to load it with `data("aaa")`.

There is no need for multiple files, you can save multiple variables in a single file, i.e.: `usethis::use_data(cars, mtcars)`.